# Spectral radius sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, spectral-radius

Let $W = S + cT$, where $|c| \le 1$ is a real constant and where $S$ and $T$ are square matrices containing real numbers from the interval $[0,1]$.

Assume moreover that the all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $S$ and $T$ satisfy $|\lambda| \le 1$. (Both matrices are right stochastic in that each row sums to one.)

Is it possible to derive an informative bound for the spectral radius of $W$? Besides being right stochastic, the matrices $S$ and $T$ do not have a special structure (e.g. Hermitian, diagonalizable, ...).

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality sufficient for you?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: According to the OP, the matrices $S$ and $T$ are not assumed to be Hermitian.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! I edited the wording of the question since the expression "weakly smaller than" for a non-strict inequality seems to be very uncommon.

Comment: Concerning the content of the question, do you assume that $c \ge 0$?

Comment: @JochenGlueck, thank you for your comment. I have eddited my orginal question, I hope it is now more clear.

Comment: Could the answer perhaps be that $A=(1+c)^{−1}W$ is again right stochastic, such that all eigenvalues $\mu$ of $A$ also satisfy $|\mu|≤1$ and all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $W$ are therefore $|\lambda|≤(c+1)$?

Comment: @Seb: If $c \in [0,1]$, then $(1+c)^{-1}W$ is again right stochastic. But if $c \in (-1,0]$, then $W$ can, of course, have negative entires.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: I think one can use Wielandt's theorem in that case. That is, suppose $W_1$ satisfies the conditions of the Perron-Frobenius theorem, then $\rho(W_2) < \rho(W_1)$ if $|W_2| < W_1$. ($\rho(\cdot)$ denotes the spectral radius here.)

It is clear that $W_2 = |S + cT| < S + |c|T = W_1$, when $c \neq 0$.

Comment: @Seb Your last bound is not particularly sharp though; even in the $1\times 1$ case you're estimating $1-c$ with $1+c$. Is that enough for your application?

Answer (score -1):

On the zero-level, treat  both $S$ and $T$ as random Ginibre matrices (not even real, just members of the GinU ensemble). Also, neglect that the spectral radius of both is one & at least one eigenvalue is exactly 1. Then, if both you right stochastic matrices are sampled randomly, their spectral bulks are discs of the radius $1/\sqrt{N}$

Then the spectral bulk of $W$ is the disc of the radius $\sqrt{\frac{1+c^2}{N}}$.

Comment: I don't think he question is asking for expected bounds on random matrices. The term "stochastic matrix" appears to be this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix and so the Ginibre ensemble is not a good model. (In particular, note that the matrix entries of S and T are required to lie in [0,1].)

Comment: @Yemon Choi From the perspective of  the support of the spectral bulk (which basically includes all eigenvalues expect the leading one, $\lambda_1 =1$), a random stochastic matrix $S$  is a real Ginibre matrix with variance of its elements equal $\sqrt(N)$. The support is not sensitive to the features of  $S$ such as normalization etc.

Comment: Regardless of the claimed universality features, the original question seems to be asking for worst-case bounds rather than that what is true "generically".

Comment: I am also not entirely convinced about the universality claims. Stochastic matrices never have negative entries, and they are constrained to have constant row sums without any corresponding constraint on the columns. I don't see why Gaussian random matrices would provide a good model. (Your claim about support of the spectral bulk certainly must depend on the mean value of each random entry, otherwise I could simply add a constant to everything.)

Comment: See this https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0567 (for random Markov chains) and this https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2361 (for random quantum operations)

Comment: "Regardless of the claimed universality features" - agree with this. This is not an attempt to answer the question; it is rather shearing of the thoughts sparked  by the question.